# Spark fault tolerance for wide dependencies

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing, fault-tolerance

I'm interested in finding out how Spark implements fault tolerance. In their [paper](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~minlanyu/teach/csci599-fall12/papers/nsdi_spark.pdf) they describe how they do it for "narrow dependencies" like map which is fairly straight forward. However, I they do not state what they do if a node crashes after a wide dependency like a sort operation. The only thing I could find is this:

> In contrast, in a lineage graph with wide dependencies, a single failed node might cause the loss of some partition from all the ancestors of an RDD, requiring a complete re-execution.

Which is not really enough for understanding what's happening.

After a sort, there is no way of telling where the data that was stored on the crashed node came from without storing some additional information. So if a crash happens after a sort, is the entire lineage re-executed or is there some mechanism reducing the computational overhead? And what about other wide dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDD dependencies are actually in terms of partitions and how they are created from partitions of other RDDs.

A **wide dependency** means the data required to create a partition is obtained from more than one partitions(from same or different RDDs).
Each partition is assigned an executor.

Now assume, we are joining two RDDs R1 and R2 that have *n* and *m* partitions respectively. Also, for the sake of simplicity, let's assume that both R1 and R2 have been calculated by *(n x m)* different executors.
We are going to create a third RDD R3 by joining R1 and R2.

When R3 is being calculated, assume a node containing *x* executors (out of *(n x m)* executors) failed for some reason. **It doesn't affect the remaining executors and their data on the other nodes.**

Only those partitions in R3 **which were supposed to be created from those failed *x* executor's data are affected. And only those *x* partitions are recreated**.

A more detailed visual explanation is available [here](https://github.com/rohitvg/scala-spark-4/wiki/Wide-vs-Narrow-Dependencies#lineages-and-fault-tolerance)

**Updated**: About Spark caching
Below URLs should help you understand the whole persistence feature of Spark

- http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence
- https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-rdd-caching.html

Comment: Coming back to the example I started with: sorting. If a partition of a RDD R2 that was created by sorting R1 is lost, is there any way to avoid sorting the **entire** RDD R1 to get the missing partition of R2?

Or from the example you linked: If a partition of G is lost, what **exactly** is recomputed here? Without storing some additional information during the groupBy and the join, I guess **everything** has to be recomputed?

Comment: You are right! But spark does keep track of the entire lineage for each of the partitions and RDDs, so it won't be necessary to re-execute all the untouched partitions. I am doubtful in the case of sorting though. That's where caching and persistence of Spark comes into the picture. To avoid unnecessary recomputation of RDDs in the case of failures.

Comment: So Spark does cache some data that could be used to recover partitions after sorting? Do you know where I could look for information on that?

Comment: I have updated the answer with useful resources. Let me know if those refs were sufficient

Comment: Thank you! Spark could recover from a failure after sorting if the sorted RDD is persisted using one of the "_2" storage levels. 
So I guess that means that without the user taking any action, Spark would have to recompute all the RDDs that lead to the sorted RDD.